# How to in "def request()" return the response directly

Tags: mitmproxy

like title, I wanna in "def request()" to process data, and return a response directly;

I don't wanna flow through the target server;

this way is feasible?  thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example on how to do that:

```py
"""Send a reply from the proxy without sending any data to the remote server."""
from mitmproxy import http


def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    if flow.request.pretty_url == "http://example.com/path":
        flow.response = http.Response.make(
            200,  # (optional) status code
            b"Hello World",  # (optional) content
            {"Content-Type": "text/html"}  # (optional) headers
        )
```

Source: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/main/examples/addons/http-reply-from-proxy.py